# Undefined object when trying to clone - but it logs correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$(window).on('drop', this.onDrop.bind(this));

p.onDrop = function(e) {
    var self = this;
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    $.each(files, function(index, file){
        self.showTemplate();
    });
};

p.showTemplate = function() {
    console.log(this.template); //logs template correctly
    var template = this.template.clone(); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
};
```

I'm not sure what is happening. I can log the template so I must have access to it, but for some reason it can not be cloned?

Comment: what is `this.template`? - is it a jQuery object or a dom element etc

Comment: can you log `console.log(this.template.clone)`

Comment: this.template is just some html. eg. this.template ='<span>etc</span>';

Comment: Is `this.template` literally a string, or a reference to a DOM element?

Comment: It's just a string of HTML, would it be a good idea to wrap it in a query object?

Comment: in that case that is the problem... you need to have a jQuery object so use `this.template = $('<span>etc</span>')`. In your case `this.template` is a string which does not have the clone method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error *`"undefined is not a function"`* is saying `.clone` is not a function. It doesn't appear to exist (as function, at least) on `this.template`.

Since you're using jQuery, you can use [`.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

```
// Shallow copy
var clone = jQuery.extend({}, this.template);

// Deep copy
var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, this.template);
```

Comment: Thanks, could i also just wrap this.template into a jquery object? this.template = $('<span></span>');

Comment: You could, yes.
Also, if it's just a string, there's no need for the `.extend`. Try this for example: `var a = '1'; var b = a; a = '2'; console.log(b)`. `b` will still be 1. Strings are stored as values, not as references.